# Increasing plotly height moves legend too far down

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I have the following plot code:

```
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list(
                [
                    dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(step="all"),
                ]
            )
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(visible=False),
        type="date",
    )
)
y_size = -2
fig.update_layout(
    legend=dict(
        y=y_size,
        x=0.0,
        itemsizing="constant",
        orientation="h",
    ),
    height=400,
    width=1600,
)
fig.update_yaxes(automargin=True)
```

With the following output (legend is hidden by yellow square for privacy):
[image]

If I change height to 800 (instead of 400) I get the following plot:

[image]

I wonder, why did the legend moved way down once I changed the graph's height?

What I want to have is: A plot with width that fits the screen without scrolling (about 1200, I don't know how to remove the scrolling), a height of about 1200, a vertical legend instead of horizontal (which can be achieved by changing orientation to orientation="v"), and a legend that starts right below and to the left size of the graph (just like the first graph).

Any ideas about how to get it? It'd be nice to simply increase the plot height and changing orientation="v". However, if I change the plot height, the legend goes too far down.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main factors that factors to consider in your case:

1. The `y` attribute of the legend dictionary when you update the layout of the figure
2. The orientation of the legend (either vertical or horizontal)

For a vertical orientation, it seems that the `y` attribute is causing some unusual behaviour when you give it a value less than 0 AND you wish to increase the height of the figure. It's almost as if its applying the `y` displacement on an outer div, which leads to greater spacing between the legend and the graph. If you wish to set a static height, then I suggest experimenting with the `y` attribute (e.g. giving it values in the range `[-0.5, -3]` when changing the height of the figure and see what suits your needs.

As for horizontal, it seems that you don't need to change the the `x` or `y` of the legend, as it'll sit horizontally, and under the graph